# Merging/overlaying jsp files into specific positions

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

I have two jsp files, one of which contains my base code that will be used by all further pages. Now i wish to merge/overlay another jsp over and above this jsp. Primarily the usage is for navigation bar, where I have a base navbar and i wish to add extra links and features but do not wish to change the base jsp's navbar and instead create a new jsp that can add new buttons/items in specific places in between the base jsps's navbar.

Comment: and your question is? you can always include the jsp's in the main one

Comment: including a jsp into another jsp is not a scalable option. I need something scalable. Another thing is that once i have created my base jsp i would not change it. The new jsp's will extend it. If say i have included one jsp in my base and now i have to add something in a different position, i would have to change my base jsp, which is not possible to do everytime. I am looking for something like layers in photoshop. @Stultuske

Comment: when that include required compile time or run time  ?

Comment: runtime @AnupamBiswas. Although the jsp must be compiled beforehand for any tag based code.

Comment: then you can think about <%@ include file=xxx" %>, It will compile once , and for the run time that file will be included

Comment: @AnupamBiswas I already suggested that, he doesn't want to do that

Comment: @Stultuske ok , I didn't check

Comment: I sounds a bit weird to me to include other JSPs dynamically to insert them in an existing navbar like that. The navbar contents should be created in your controller and then use one JSP for the navbar which is populated by the controller data. Your question is a little unclear.. to me at least..

Comment: I have already tried that option, but there is a performance issue with that option. I have an application with nearly 10,000 different screens and to load a navbar from populated data clearly takes a toll on my performance metrics. @JackFlamp

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can do it by using . So when you run your base file it include this "included" file also. This can be use to reduce code and to make application more readable. It also reduce execution time.